# wgpu-rs: Putting a Matrix3 into a vertex shader results in odd behavior but using a Matrix4 works fine

Tags: rust, shader

Using wgpu-rs, I'm trying to get a 3x3 cgmath matrix into a shader (compiled using glsl-to-spirv). However, the resulting mat3 in the shader has incorrect data. When I replace the mat3 and Matrix3 with mat4 and Matrix4, everything works fine and the matrix has correct data.

Vertex Shader:

```
layout(set=0, binding=0) uniform Uniforms {
    mat3 camera_transform;
};
```

Render Loop:

```
let mut encoder = self.device.create_command_encoder(
    &wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor {
        label: Some("update encoder"),
    },
);
let staging_buffer = self.device.create_buffer_with_data(
    bytemuck::cast_slice(&[self.uniforms]),
    wgpu::BufferUsage::COPY_SRC,
);
encoder.copy_buffer_to_buffer(&staging_buffer, 0, &self.uniform_buffer, 0, std::mem::size_of::<Uniforms>() as wgpu::BufferAddress);
self.queue.submit(&[encoder.finish()]);

// ...

render_pass.set_bind_group(0, &self.uniform_bind_group, &[]);
```

Uniforms:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Uniforms {
    pub camera_transform: Matrix3::<f32>,
}

unsafe impl bytemuck::Pod for Uniforms {}
unsafe impl bytemuck::Zeroable for Uniforms {}

impl Uniforms {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            camera_transform: Matrix3::identity(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could be running into this issue: https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu-rs/issues/36?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu-rs/issues/36) in `wgpu-rs`. Indeed the simplest workaround may be to make your mat3 into a mat4 until it is resolved.

The problem seems to be a mistake of alignment in generating `SPIR-V`. The actual alignment is:

> 1. If the member is a scalar consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is N.
> 2. If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N,
>      respectively.
> 3. If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 4N.
> 4. If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array
>      element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up to the
>      base alignment of a vec4. The array may have padding at the end; the
>      base offset of the member following the array is rounded up to the
>      next multiple of the base alignment.

You are in case 4. Having a mat4 should leave no extra padding on the end and not give any possibility for misalignment issues.